# VBA copy row based on multiple column criteria

Tags: vba

I am trying to code a row search based on multiple criteria, that will then copy rows which match the criteria. Example below.

```
1         2   3
B         C   D
B         D   C
C         B   D
C         D   B
D         B   C
D         C   B
```

I have written code that will work based on if the criteria in the first column. What I need though is the code to be able to work no matter which column or number of columns has criteria values. (ex. if criteria for column 1 was B and 3 was C it would copy only row BDC, or if the criteria for column 3 was D it would copy both BCD and CBD) My current written code is missing this criteria but I will copy below.

```
Private Sub listgen()
    Sheets("Segments").Activate
    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim c As Long 'columns
    Dim d As Long
    Dim e As Long
    Dim r As Long 'rows
    Dim tr As Long 'total rows

    r = 3
    a = 1
    c = 3
    tr = Sheets("Trips").Cells(Rows.Count, a).End(xlUp).Row
    e = c + a

    Do
    d = a
    b = 8
        If Sheets("Trips").Cells(r, d).Value = Range("E2") Then
        Do
            Sheets("Trips").Cells(r, d).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Segments").Cells(r, b)
            d = d + 1
            b = b + 1
            Loop Until d = e
        End If
    r = r + 1
    Loop Until r = tr

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As written the only thing you want us to do is refactor (and a decent size refactor at that) the code for you. You don't show the attempts you've made to accomplish the desired task and where it's not working, just the code you have that doesn't fit the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `AutoFilter()` in the following helper sub

```
Private Sub listgen(criteriaCols As Variant, criteriaVals As Variant)
    Dim iCriterium As Long

    With Worksheets("Trips") '<--| reference your "data" worksheet
        With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:C cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty row
            For iCriterium = 0 To UBound(criteriaCols) '<--| loop through filter list
                .AutoFilter field:=criteriaCols(iCriterium), Criteria1:=criteriaVals(iCriterium) '<--| filter on current filter column with current filter value
            Next
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Worksheets("Segments").Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| if any cells filtered other than headers (row 1) then past them to "target" sheet from its column H first empty cell after last not empty one
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

and call it from your "main" sub passing it your list of columns to filter on and corresponding list of values to filter with, as follows

```
listgen Array(1, 3), Array("B", "C")  '<--| filter on columns 1 and 3 with, correspondingly, values "B" and "C"
listgen Array(3), Array("D")  '<--| filter on column 3 with values "D"
```

Comment: @Gelon, did you get through it?